# how to iterate over multiple dataframes and add values to new dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 4 data frames:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('values1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('values2.csv')
df3 = pd.read_csv('values3.csv')
df4 = pd.read_csv('values4.csv')
```

each of them have a structure as follows:
[image]

I want to create a new data frame such that it has aggregated values for each category in all the data frames. So, the new data frame should have values which are calculated using the formula :-

```
Total['values'][0] = df1['values'][0] / (df1['values'][0] + df2['values'][0]  + df3['values'][0]  + df4['values'][0] )
```

Like this it should generate values for all the rows. 
Can someone please help me out.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First join all `DataFrame`s with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and aggregate `sum` for `Series` and then convert column `category` to index for `Series` from `df1` and divide by [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
s = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4]).groupby('category')['values'].sum()

out = df1.set_index('category')['values'].div(s).reset_index(name='total')
```

EDIT:

```
s = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4]).groupby('category')['values'].sum()
s1 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('category')['values'].sum()

out = s1.div(s2).reset_index(name='new')
```

Comment: what if I have to add df1 values and df2 values in the numerator and divide by the sum ?

Comment: Cool!!!!! Thanks alot! I thought I'll have to apply some very series for loops :p

Comment: Can you help me with one more thing.in each data frame I have 3 values columns, namely: value1, value2, value. I want to create a new data frame which has summed values row-wise for each category. I am not able to apply the above code for multiple columns

Comment: @user8306074 - I think you need `s = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df4]).groupby('category')['value1','value2','value'].sum().sum(axis=1)`

Comment: I think I'll create different lists and append them into one data frame

Comment: @user8306074 - Maybe not understand, is possible see some data sample and mainly expacted output? e.g. for 2 rows in 2 dataframes?